# How to perform linear regression in sklearn with a custom loss function

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am running a linear regression in sklearn

```py
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(x_poly, y_true)
```

Instead of using the standard loss function (I think is MSE) to fit my linear regression. I would like to define a distance metric with a symmetric definite positive matrix A, i.e., the norm ||.||_{A^{-1}}. Is there a way to define this parameter?

Comment: I don't think sklearn supports custom loss function in general.  There could be a chance for a specific loss function.  Can you write down explicitly the loss function that you want to use?

Comment: Might this [blog post](https://alex.miller.im/posts/linear-model-custom-loss-function-regularization-python/) help?